# Why is it that $\angle QPR=\angle ABC + \angle ACB$?

Tags: geometry

$\angle ABC + \angle PQC = \angle ACB +\angle PRB =90^\circ$

$X$ is the midpoint of $BC$, $Y$ is the midpoint of $AC$, and $Z$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

Why is it that $\angle QPR=\angle ABC + \angle ACB$ ? I know it has something to do with $\angle ABC + \angle PQC = \angle ACB +\angle PRB =90^\circ$. But could somebody please break this down for me?

[image]

Comment: Hint: Assume $\angle QXP = x$. Can you find $\angle QPX$ in terms of x and $\angle ABC$?

Comment: Angle chasing. $PQ$ and $PR$ are perpendicular to $CA$ and $BA$, respectively (by the angle conditions you have set up), and thus $\measuredangle QPR = 180^\circ - \measuredangle CAB = \measuredangle ABC + \measuredangle ACB$.

Comment: Maybe $\angle QPR = 180^\circ - \angle PQC -\angle PRB = 90^\circ -\angle PQC + 90^\circ-\angle PRB = \angle ABC + \angle ACB$.

Comment: Sorry to say that I found your question has many un-explained items in it. (1) First of all, why $\angle PXR$ was drawn as if it is a right angle? Or is it? (2) Assuming that the first sentence is a given, then according to @GAVD ‘s comment, he/she has properly answered your query. However, the question is “none of the given midpoints have been used.” Are they smoke-screens? Or your question was NOT completely stated?!

Answer (score 0):

$ \angle ABC $ = $ \angle QPX $ and $ \angle ACB $ = $ \angle XPR $
This is because the mid points $Z$ ,  $Y$ , $X$ are also intersections for the sides of the two main angular figures $ \angle PQR $ and angle $ \angle ABC $
Also take note that
$ \angle QPX $ + $ \angle ZPR $ = $ \angle QPR $